# Is there a way to count the elements generated by an XSL within the same XSL?

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0

If I have an XSL that creates output like this simple/rough example:

```
<Parent1>
  <ABC><xsl:value-of select="SomeValue1"/></ABC>
  <DEF><xsl:value-of select="SomeValue2"/></DEF>
  <GHI><xsl:value-of select="SomeValue3"/></GHI>
  ... 
  <YZ><xsl:value-of select="SomeValue9"/></YZ>
</Parent1>
```

... within this same XSL, how can I count how many children the XSL will produce?

Comment: It depends on how the stylesheet decides whether to create those elements or not. Please post a [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can generate your content into a variable, count the children in the variable, and then emit the content of the variable:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
    
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:variable name="temp-results">
            <Parent1>
                <ABC><xsl:value-of select="SomeValue1"/></ABC>
                <DEF><xsl:value-of select="SomeValue2"/></DEF>
                <GHI><xsl:value-of select="SomeValue3"/></GHI>
                ... 
                <YZ><xsl:value-of select="SomeValue9"/></YZ>
            </Parent1>
        </xsl:variable>
        
        <xsl:text>Number of children:</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="count($temp-results/Parent1/*)"/>
        <xsl:sequence select="$temp-results"/>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: By selecting this as the "answer", I'm not suggesting anyone else's solution and feedback was not a good solution.  I tried this one first and it solved my issue.  I appreciate everyone's contribution to assist me here. Thank you!

Comment: But at least for the benefit of others, if not yours, it should be noted that this is probably not the best solution. Since you did not follow my suggestion to post a [mcve], we cannot be sure in your case - but in most cases this is an unnecessary waste of memory and CPU cycles.

Answer (score 1):

One possibility is wrapping the whole output process in a variable and then count its descendants.
So, for example, you can use the following XSLT code

```
<xsl:template match="/Parent1">
    <xsl:variable name="output">
        <ABC><xsl:value-of select="SomeValue1"/><ZZZ>Some Grandchild</ZZZ></ABC>
        <DEF><xsl:value-of select="SomeValue2"/></DEF>
        <GHI><xsl:value-of select="SomeValue3"/></GHI>
        ... 
        <YZ><xsl:value-of select="SomeValue9"/></YZ>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:value-of select="concat('Outputting ', count($output/descendant::*), ' elements.&#xa;')" />
    <xsl:copy-of select="$output" />
</xsl:template>
```

Its output is

```
Outputting 5 elements.
<ABC>
    <ZZZ>Some Grandchild</ZZZ>
</ABC>
<DEF/>
<GHI/>
... 
<YZ/>
```

This code accomplishes three things:

1. First it generates the result and puts it into the variable
2. It counts all the

   - children (`child::*` axis) or
   - descendants (`descendant::*` axis) as in the example above

   of the elements in the variable
3. It copies the variable to the output stream

This approach can even be nested - meaning that it can be applied several times, one after another.

Answer (score 1):

Your choices are:

(a) find a way of computing the result as a function of the input

(b) capture the output in a variable and run a second phase of processing against that variable.

(c) a blend of the above: compute some intermediate result in a variable, and use that variable as input to both processes.

In the example you've given, the first approach works perfectly well; but I guess your real problem is more complex than that, otherwise you wouldn't be asking.

Comment: And, it should be added, (a) is much preferable to (b) or (c) - which is why (b) should not be suggested before determining that (a) is impossible or not viable.

Comment: In many cases (c) is best. For example, `<xsl:variable name="selected-items" select="items[--predicate--]"/><xsl:apply-templates select="$selected-items"/><xsl:value-of select="count($selected-items)"/>`

Comment: I agree. My point is that we don't know what is the case  here.